# Where can I find pending message on the message queue in android?

Tags: android, message-queue

Is there a way to find out the message queue size and what item is in each message? Is it `Looper.getMainLoop` or something?

Comment: You shouldn't be messing around with your app's message queue.  At least not the main UI thread.  It only makes sense to look at message queues for things like helper threads, where you can actually send messages and handle them properly.  However, touching the main UI thread message queue is something you don't really have too much of a reason to do so.

Comment: Hi Kristopher, thank you for your reply. but can you at least tell me how to find out how many items are on the message quueue? or inspect it so that i can cancel it it if i need to?

Comment: The Message Queue is opaque.  If you're trying to look at your main app's message queue, it's going to have a bunch of junk on it that doesn't make any sense for you to handle (i.e., if you tried to mess with it your app would crash, message queues are used for outgoing intents, etc..., not just Message objects).  There is no method to do this, if you look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html

Answer (score 3):

Hope it's not too late for an answer. You can access the current thread's message queue calling Looper.myQueue() on it. However, the MessageQueue class has no methods to find out its size or what item is in each message. For that purpose, you could try the Handler class. A handler manages a looper, which has a queue, and that handler has methods like hasMessages, obtainMessage, removeMessages, and so on. I think that is your best shot.