# How is it possible to count the number of messages queued in a Handler?

Tags: android, event-handling

I am using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and I'd like to count the number of messages that are pending. However, I don't see a method that allows me to obtain this information.

Is it possible ?

It seems that because there's a `hasMessages(int what)`, why not expose something like `getMessageCount(int what)` ?

Comment: See comments here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478111/android-where-can-i-find-pending-message-on-the-message-queue-in-android.  the method you cited as analogous is for lookup, not enumeration.

Comment: actually there isn't a method "hasMessages(int what)", there is "getMessageName (Message message)"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using a Handler, a better solution is to implement a Queue.

Comment: I think something like a BlockingDeque<E> is great : one can put high priority items in the top and the low priority items in the bottom. Additionally, the size() method addresses the need to figure out how much is left to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simply keep a separate counter, incrementing it when I add to the queue and decrementing it in the runnable. It will want to be declared as `volatile` to make it visible at all times to all threads.